# Production Possibility Frontier for 3 goods

Tags: microeconomics, production-function

Is it possible to construct a Production Possibility Frontier (PPF)  for 3 goods? Would this require a 3D graph and a part of a sphere, in one quadrant (as opposed to the usual 2D plot, with a part of a circle in one quadrant).

Is this something used in more complex analysis of production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. In fact you can construct PPF for arbitrary number of goods.

When it comes to plotting it for a case of 3 goods it is easy to make 2D projection of the 3D space. You can see the image below for an example.

[image]

Also note PPF is not necessary spherical or circular. The shape of PPF depends on the opportunity cost. In textbooks you might sometimes see it represented like a portion of a circle or elipse but it does not necessarily have to have that shape.